# Copying tomcat7 directory creates hard link?

Tags: tomcat

I copied the tomcat7 directory and renamed it. Using Ubuntu 14.04. Im trying to change port numbers in each copy in order to run multiple instances. However changing one server.xml changes the server.xml in all copies. They are always in sync. As if a hard link was created when I copied them. What is going on?

Comment: I would suggest to verify the existence of links if any to the server.xml using 'ls -l' command. Alternately, Try modifying other files like startup.sh (you can insert dummy lines using comments prefix with #). Check if the behavior is same for these scripts as well. Lastly, you can verify the underlying storage associated with this multiple instances. Check if any third party software is trying to sync these directories

Comment: Yes the conf folder is linked to the etc/tomcat7 folder. Im not sure how to copy actual directory as opposed to just a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to make a copy of the actual files rather than copy the links, is to use `tar` with option `-h`.

1. create a tar file: `cd /opt/tomcat7; tar -c -h -f /tmp/copy.tar .`
2. create a new location: `mkdir /opt/tomcat7bis`
3. unpack the tar to the new location: `cd /opt/tomcat7bis; tar -x -f /tmp/copy.tar .`